# Creating A ListView With Stacked List Items in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I stumbled upon this design in dribble
[image]

and in trying to implement it in flutter I was able to create the curves using clip Path. this is what I have[image]

I am trying to get rid of the space in between the shapes so that they can collapse.

this is my CurvedRectangleClipper:`
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
class CurvedRectangleClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
final double offset = 80;
@override
Path getClip(Size size) {
    // TODO: implement getClip
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - offset);
    var firstEndpoint = Offset(offset, size.height);
    path.arcToPoint(firstEndpoint, radius: Radius.circular(-offset),clockwise: false);

    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, offset);
    path.lineTo(offset, offset);

    var secondEndPoint = Offset(0,0);

    path.arcToPoint(secondEndPoint, radius: Radius.circular(-offset),clockwise: true);
    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
}

@override
bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper oldClipper) {
    // TODO: implement shouldReclip
    return true;
}
}
```

`and this is my main.dart file:`
    import 'package:devotion/CurvedRectangleClipper.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() {
runApp(HomeScreen());
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    home: MainScreen(),
    title: 'Devotion',
    theme: appTheme,
    );
}
}

var appTheme =
    ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Oxygen', primaryColor: Colors.purpleAccent);

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Devotion'),
    ),
    body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
        CurvedListItem(
            title: 'Yoga and Meditation for Beginners',
            time: 'TODAY 5:30 PM'),
        CurvedListItem(
            title: 'Practice French, English And Chinese',
            time: 'TUESDAY 5:30 PM',
        ),
        CurvedListItem(
            title: 'Adobe XD Live Event in Europe',
            time: 'FRIDAY 6:00 PM',
        ),
        ],
    ),
    );
}
}

class CurvedListItem extends StatelessWidget {
final String title;
final String time;
final String people;
final IconData icon;

CurvedListItem({this.title, this.time, this.icon, this.people});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
    clipper: CurvedRectangleClipper(),
    child: Container(
        color: Colors.pink,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 32,
        top: 100,
        bottom: 50,
        ),
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
            Text(
                time,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
            ),
            SizedBox(
                height: 2,
            ),
            Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 22,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            Row(),
            ]),
    ),
    );
}
}
```

`
I guess the top curve is not needed if the items are placed on each other but I left it there to know the actual shape. 
Corrections and comments are also welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot get rid of the space between the clipped widgets. There is a easy and different approach you can take to solve this.

Here is how I would have done it:

```
void main() {
  runApp(HomeScreen());
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MainScreen(),
      title: 'Devotion',
      theme: appTheme,
    );
  }
}

ThemeData appTheme = ThemeData(
  fontFamily: 'Oxygen',
  primaryColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
);

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Devotion'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          CurvedListItem(
            title: 'Yoga and Meditation for Beginners',
            time: 'TODAY 5:30 PM',
            color: Colors.red,
            nextColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          CurvedListItem(
            title: 'Practice French, English And Chinese',
            time: 'TUESDAY 5:30 PM',
            color: Colors.green,
            nextColor: Colors.yellow,
          ),
          CurvedListItem(
            title: 'Adobe XD Live Event in Europe',
            time: 'FRIDAY 6:00 PM',
            color: Colors.yellow,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CurvedListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const CurvedListItem({
    this.title,
    this.time,
    this.icon,
    this.people,
    this.color,
    this.nextColor,
  });

  final String title;
  final String time;
  final String people;
  final IconData icon;
  final Color color;
  final Color nextColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: nextColor,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: color,
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            bottomLeft: Radius.circular(80.0),
          ),
        ),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          left: 32,
          top: 80.0,
          bottom: 50,
        ),
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                time,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 2,
              ),
              Text(
                title,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 22,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Row(),
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Here is the output]

Note: I don't claim it to be optimal, but still easy and neat.

Hope that helped!

Comment: This was an easy and the neat way I could have thinked of, was expecting to learn something new! but yeah Simple works in Flutter! Thanks for keeping it simple.

Answer (score 2):

Use Align and set **heightFactor**: 0.75 and  **alignment**: Alignment.topCenter,

```
 ListView(
  children: [
    Align(
      heightFactor: 0.75,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: CurvedListItem(
        title: 'Yoga and Meditation for Beginners',
        time: 'TODAY 5:30 PM',
      ),
    ),
    Align(
      heightFactor: 0.75,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: CurvedListItem(
        title: 'Practice French, English And Chinese',
        time: 'TUESDAY 5:30 PM',
      ),
    ),
    Align(
      heightFactor: 0.75,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      child: CurvedListItem(
        title: 'Adobe XD Live Event in Europe',
        time: 'FRIDAY 6:00 PM',
      ),
    )
  ],
);
```