# Overlay/translate ListView builder items clipped with a custom ClipPath

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm generating multiple widgets(Containers in this case) using a ListView.builder and I also use a custom ClipPath to give a custom shape to them.

I was wondering if would it be possible to translate or somehow overlay those list items in order to place them so that the background(black area in the attached screenshot) would be covered. By that I mean I want to place them right under each other, like puzzle pieces. To be able to fit them right under each other would probably mean they would have to be overlayed somehow. Was googling but without any success.

Hopefully there's some Flutter experts out there who are nice enough to guide me. Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating A ListView With Stacked List Items in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55094697/creating-a-listview-with-stacked-list-items-in-flutter)

Comment: @HemanthRaj Indeed, the only difference is that my list items should be created using a ListView.builder and the items should have dynamic height based on the content displayed within.

Comment: I think same solution can be used, however you would have to specify a constant corner radius.

Comment: Probably true, but I'd also need to be able to have a tap event on each item. So the trick with passing the next color is easy and neat, but that corner should also react to the tap for its color. If you know what I mean.