# Im looking for a flutter library that will allow me to place two cards on top of eachother

Tags: flutter, flutter-packages

Im looking for a flutter library that will allow me to place two cards on top of eachother and able to click on the one behind to bring it to the front and vice versa, such as the picture:

[image: example]

If there isn't a library, would you know how to make something similar within flutter? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know a library, I think that with a ListView you could achieve it, this post can help you.

[Creating A ListView With Stacked List Items in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55094697/creating-a-listview-with-stacked-list-items-in-flutter)

[here another example:](https://github.com/retroportalstudio/flutter_itemstack_listview)